# How to return a promise inside the async await in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it ok to do something like this?

I mean, Is `return await new Promise()`  a valid expression as of below?:

```
  async pushImage(image, basePath) {
    const imgId = this.angularDatabase.createPushId();
    const route = `${basePath}${imgId}`;
    const imageRef = this.angularFireStorage.ref(route);
    
    return await concat( 
      imageRef.put(image.image).snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
      defer(() => imageRef.getDownloadURL())
    )
      .pipe(
        map(
          (url) => (
             { ...image, url }
          )
        )
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: If you await and then return I guess it will just return normal value not promise

Comment: Because the function is `async` it will always return a promise value! You don't technically need the `return await` and you could defer the `await` to the callee of `pushImage`

Comment: You don't need to use `async await` at all. Just return the result. Also, whatever you return from an async function is always a Promise.

Comment: Yeah. But async/await should be used together right??

Comment: @mex ... yes, you need `async` to use `await` ... but since your only promise is the last statement, you don't need to use `async/await` for that function, the result will always be a Promise anyway - i.e. if there's only ONE promise, and it's the thing that is being returned, there's no need to await .... so there's no need for async

Comment: async/await are just more advance and compact versions of Promises. you put 'await' in front of code where you wanted it to behave like a promise and you are good to go.

Comment: so basically when you use 'await' you don't need to convert it into a promise explicitly.

Comment: JaromandaX's Rule #1 for `async` functions ... you never need to `return await somePromise` - just `return somePromise` - Rule #2, if a function never uses `await` it never needs to be `async` (mild caveat - if the caller expects a Promise and uses `.then` syntax - this will break the caller)

Answer (score 1):

Anything returned from an async functions comes out as a promise.

For example:

```
async getDate() {
   return new Date();
}
```

will return a promise with the contents of a date.

An example of reading this overly complicated `getDate()` function would be:

```
getDate().then(date => {
   console.log("The date: ", date);
});
```

However, you can also return a promise. This makes your code above perfectly valid, except you don't need to include the `await` in the return.

You can "simply" just say

```
return concat( 
          imageRef.put(image.image).snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
          defer(() => imageRef.getDownloadURL())
       ).pipe(
          map(url => {
             return {...image, url}
          })
       ).toPromise();
```

Side note: I am not certain, but I think you should return the object in the map. Changing `{...image, url}` to `return {...image, url}`

Additional response:

To retrieve the contents of a promise, use the .then() method. Example:

```
myReturnedPromise.then(dataOfMyReturnedPromise => {
   //This code is called after the promise is resolved.
   console.log("The returned value is: ", dataOfMyReturnedPromise);
}).catch(error => {
   //If this code is called, the promise completed with an error
   //This might be executed if you're retreiving data from the internet
   //and your internet connection is too poor to get the data
   console.error("Error: ", error);
});
```

If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. is it ok to return a promise inside a ```then() {}``` block?

Comment: @mex - yes, it is, the Promise that the `.then` returns will "become" the Promise you return in a `.then`

Comment: @mex, I've extended my answer to include a response to your question. Also, if this answered your question, please consider marking this as the accepted answer (check mark button).